# Why does the AM-GM inequality not show $25 \csc^2(\theta) +16 \sin^2(\theta)$ has a minimum of $41$ as the graph indicates?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let's say we have to find range of $f(\theta) = 25 \csc^2(\theta) +16 \sin^2(\theta)$

If I use  $AM \ge GM$

Then $f(\theta) \ge 40$

Which tells minimum value of $f(\theta)$ will be $40$

But I checked it on graphing calculator and it is showing $41$ will be minimum value

Then I tried for
$f(\theta) = 16 \csc^2(\theta) +25 \sin^2(\theta)$

Now using $AM \ge GM$

I am getting 40 as answer of minimum value of function and also checked on graphing calculator

> Now my question is why  my first question answer is wrong using $AM \ge GM$

I think it is something related to coefficient but I am not getting it how it is wrong

Comment: can you elaborate how did you use AM-GM inequality?

Comment: @DS   (25 cosec²x + 16 sin²x)/2 >= √(25*16)      sorry if u can't understand I don't know how to write you use special keys to write maths .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple reason is that it does not give a minimum; it gives a lower bound, but it's not necessarily the largest or best lower bound.

Equality is achieved in AM-GM when each number is equal, i.e.

$$\frac{x+y}{2} = \sqrt{xy} \iff x=y$$

Of course, $f(\theta) \ge 40$ and the existence of $\theta_0$ such that $f(\theta_0) = 40$ would validate that the minimum is $40$, but the question remains: is there ever an $\theta$ for which

$$25 \csc^2 \theta \stackrel{?}{=} 16 \sin^2 \theta$$

holds?

Try graphing it and you will see that no $\theta$ works:

[image]

This also explains why the case of reversed coefficients work: graph $16 \csc^2 \theta$ and $25 \sin^2 \theta$, and you will find that the graphs sometimes intersect, so the AM-GM inequality will perfectly and accurately describe the minimum of their sum.

Comment: That's it.  now can you tell me that how solution for this ( when csc² coefficient is larger) is given by book  a²+b²...( Sum of squares of coefficient)

Comment: Because of the AM-GM inequality and the fact that $\csc \theta \sin \theta = 1$. It's just that, in the first case (in the graph above), the coefficients were not large enough to have the ranges/graphs intersect.

Comment: Then how to come to a²+b² answer.